# JSON parsing using C

Tags: c, json

I know this is a seemingly easy topic that has been covered a million times, but I'm very stuck in following other examples. But I'm struggling to follow along with a lot of examples online, and I've looked at a lot of them . I currently have a JSON file that I'm trying to pull the "price" value out of but every example that I've tried to follow I've been stuck and confused, so this is my last resort.

```
{"success":true,"errors":[],"results":[{"productConditionId":3442759,"price":169.54,"lowestRange":155.00,"highestRange":229.95}]}
```

[JSON FILE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0X5R.png)

I would like to be able to have the the price "168.54" as a int that I can assign to a variable.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use frozen library  https://github.com/cesanta/frozen json_scanf function, is very usefull.

Comment: *"168.54" as an int*. Do you mean 168 or 169? :) or maybe 16854?

Comment: There are JSON-parsing libraries available for C.  Software recommendations are off-topic here, but Google should help you find several.  Choose one and use it.

Comment: I've tried using ArduinoJson, JSON-C, and I've followed along with other tutorials but the examples they are using are very hard to follow. Like this one ... https://community.particle.io/t/tutorial-webhooks-and-responses-with-parsing-json-mustache-tokens/14612

Comment: [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) is popular.

Comment: “...have the price 168.54 as an int...” Hmm. Does not compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check frozen library https://github.com/cesanta/frozen is tiny, portable and without dependencies.

For your case here the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "frozen.c"

static void scan_array(const char *str, int len, void *user_data) {
    struct json_token t;
    int i;
    float price;
    int casted;

    printf("Parsing array: %.*s\n", len, str);
    for (i = 0; json_scanf_array_elem(str, len, "", i, &t) > 0; i++) {
      printf("Index %d, token %.*s\n", i, t.len, t.ptr);
      json_scanf(t.ptr, t.len, "{price: %f}", &price);
      casted = (int)price;
      printf("Price %.2f : price casted %d \n", price, casted);

    }
}

int main(void) {

    const char *str =
      "{\"success\":true,\"errors\":[],\"results\":[{\"productConditionId\":3442759,\"price\":169.54,\"lowestRange\":155.00,\"highestRange\":229.95}]}";

    printf("Parsing %s \n", str);
    json_scanf(str, strlen(str), "{results: [%M]}", &scan_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing {"success":true,"errors":[],"results":[{"productConditionId":3442759,"price":169.54,"lowestRange":155.00,"highestRange":229.95}]} 
Parsing array: [{"productConditionId":3442759,"price":169.54,"lowestRange":155.00,"highestRange":229.95}]
Index 0, token {"productConditionId":3442759,"price":169.54,"lowestRange":155.00,"highestRange":229.95}
Price 169.54 : price casted 169
```